# Xcode and iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using an older version of Xcode - 3.1.3. and want to install the iPhone SDK.

Can anyone point me to which version of the SDK I need to download? I tried to search for the appropriate information but could not find anything that matched.

Thanks

Comment: You need to just download the latest xcode and sdk.  For one, it will be a lot better for you to develop on.  Also, Apple is not very good at supporting older versions of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the ability to update Xcode to a more current version, you will be unable to develop on a lot of the latest SDKs. iOS 5 for example was never made compatible with Xcode 3 versions. So until you are able to upgrade to Xcode 4, you'll be stuck with the iOS 4 SDKs.

Good Luck!

Comment: I see.. I wish it was otherwise but that's the best I can do at the moment. Is there a link on the Apple site where I can download the iOS 4 SDK?

I looked for it and found it on other websites but not on the official site..

Answer (score 3):

you download the xcode 4 from apple developer site. Its the best to develop iphone apps.

Comment: Or if you have Lion, just grab it from the App Store.

Comment: Downloading the latest version is not an option. I can only work with 3.1.3 at the moment..